# Need to include separate components of charts (chart.js) with settings in other (dashboard) component

Tags: angular, angular7

I have four separate components with four different types of charts in each **(chart.js)** which also includes the settings of the charts. I want to include specific charts on the basis of backend response on different components.

I am using **@ViewChild** for accessing methods/variables of a particular component and  in dashboard.component.html for including the component's HTML. I am using ***ngFor** as i am getting response from backend and then using ***ngIf** for calling/including specific

I have also tried ComponentFactory creating specific component but left this approach as i was unable to access included component's methods.

```
<--HTML CODE-->
<div class="col-xl-6 mb-4" *ngFor="let graphs of 
 dashboardRes?.data?.dashboard_graphs">
<app-sales-pipeline *ngIf="graphs?.chart_detail?.type == 
'horizontal_bar_chart'"></app-sales-pipeline>
<app-line-chart *ngIf="graphs?.chart_detail?.type == 'line_chart'"></app- 
line-chart>
<app-gauge-chart *ngIf="graphs?.chart_detail?.type == 'guage_chart'"> 
</app-gauge-chart>
</div>

<--TS CODE-->
@ViewChild(LineChartComponent) lineChart: LineChartComponent;
@ViewChild(BarChartComponent) barChart: BarChartComponent;
@ViewChild(GaugeChartComponent) gaugeChart: GaugeChartComponent;

// Not using this approach as i was unable to access included component's methods.
createBarChart(): void {
const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = 
this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BarChartComponent);
this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

I want to dynamically include chart components where ever needed in the app. I also want to call their specific methods for retrieving chart-data via API. Type of chart, settings of charts and quantity of charts are coming in the Dashboard API where as chart-data should come with its specific component (as i will be including these charts in reports page too - with different data). My major concern is to change **settings of a specific chart and save them** using API (settings are coming in dashboard API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to not reuse components methods. You can start the components as you are already doing it with ***ngFor** and ***ngIf**, but you can set dynamicaly the settings coming from the API as an input and set when component starts. If you want to reuse the data already fetched from dashboard, you can pass the graph model to the child components, otherwise you can use angular lifecycle to call the api on each component on **ngOnInit()**.

If you want the reuse the charts already fetched, your charts components would have inputs like this:

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() chartModel: ChartModel;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.methodIWantToCallToUpdateSettings();
  }

  methodIWantToCallToUpdateSettings(): void {
     //do your thing
  }
}
```

And your dashboard.component.html would look like this:

```
<app-bar-chart *ngIf="graphs?.chart_detail?.type == 'bar_chart'" [chartModel]="graphs">
```

Now if you want call it dynamicaly by each component, just add your calls for the back end on the **ngOnInit()** chart components, and pass the parameters you want to pass by the input as well.

Something like this:

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parameter: string;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.callToBackEnd(this.parameter);
  }

  callToBackEnd(parameter: string): void {
     //do your thing on backend
  }
}
```